# convert encoding in php doesn't convert between ASCII and UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ascii

is UTF-8 not the same as ASCII? how you would explain the different results i get from:

```
$result = mb_detect_encoding($PLAINText, mb_detect_order(), true);
```

Sometimes i get "UTF-8" in $result and sometimes i get "ASCII". so they are different, but that is not my question, my question is why iconv() code doesn't convert from ASCII to UTF-8?

```
$result = iconv("ASCII","UTF-8//IGNORE",$PLAINText);
```

i check the $result encoding later using the mb_detect_encoding() function and it is still "ASCII" , not "UTF-8".

Comment: *"i know that UTF-8 is almost the same as ASCII"* - What? Hell, no. Recommended reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Thanks, i edit the post so people won't be mistaken. so why the iconv() doesn't convert from ASCII to UTF-8?

Comment: It UTF-8 was the same as ASCII they'd call it ASCII. It just happens that the 127 characters of ASCII have the same byte value in UTF-8. Have you read the article I linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when using only ASCII characters in an UTF-8 string, the UTF-8 string is indistinguishable from an ASCII string. (Unless a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is used, but it's optional.)